# Some important metrics for rabbitmq are missing

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, prometheus, metrics

i have rabbitmq with helm installed on my k8s cluster where i also have prometheus and grafana stack there. . The thing is i want to create alerts based on some important metrics like:
rabbitmq_running, rabbitmq_up, rabbitmq_node_mem_used, rabbitmq_node_mem_limit and they do not appear in prometheus i get empty query result.

I expected to see these metrics because i am using the built-in Prometheus metrics plugin that will expose all RabbitMQ metrics in Prometheus format. I see a lot of metrics but no the one mentioned like rabbitmq_running, rabbitmq_up, rabbitmq_node_mem_used, rabbitmq_node_mem_limit and they do not appear in prometheus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to install the rabbitmq-exporter as well not just use the Prometheus rabbitmq plugin. Now I use both of them.